# PHP: read value of input field

Tags: php, post

I have a very basic question about PHP. So, there is `index.php` that includes a form. This form contains input field `field1`:

**index.php**

```
    <div id="container1">
    <form name="optform" method="post" action="processing.php">
                <div class = "box">
                    <label for="field1"><span>Bla bla bla:</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="input-text" value="5" size="11" maxlength="11" name="field1" id="field1">
                </div>
                <br/>
            <div class="buttons">
                <a href="" class="regular" onclick="click_function();return false;">Run</a>
            </div>
    </form>
    </div>

    <div id="container2">

    </div>

    <script language="javascript">
    function click_function() {
         $('#container2').load('processing.php');
    }
    </script>
```

I need to use the value from `field1` in another PHP file called as `processing.php`. So, how can I read this value from `processing.php`? Should I do something like this in `processing.php`:?

**processing.php**

```
$field1value = $_POST["field1"];
```

Comment: Include processing.php in index.php and execute the code under condition that POST is set. This is one option. You could also set the form action to processing.php and then redirect back to index.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The action attribute specifies the URL that the browser will submit to. That is currently `index.php`.

If you want to use code in `processing.php` to handle the form data, then *index must include processing*, not the other way around. (As the code stands, `processing.php` won't be involved at all, so can't include anything).

Alternatively, change the action to point to `processing.php`.

Comment: using one common entry point for the app is usually better, I would vote for `index.php`

Comment: @KlausosKlausos You can now access that value in processing.php. If you still want to use that value in index.php though you will have to do it differently (include processing.php for example)

Comment: @Bono: I want to see field1 in processing.php. So, I assume it's fine now.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos: Why have you included processing.php at the top? since the action is now set to processing.php, the POSTed data will be visible in that file..

Answer (score 2):

You should `POST` the form to `processing.php`

```
<form name="optform" method="post" action="processing.php">
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to do it you can store it in a [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)
you can put the `action` attribute to "processing.php", which will submit all POST values to that file.
You could also [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) processing.php with your index.php

Answer (score 0):

Since the action of your  is set to index.php, the data I feel will be POSTed to index.php itself. Instead of that, why not include action="processing.php" ?